# persistent SSH connection while connecting to VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

I have a Linux machine on the intranet which I can only access via `ssh`, this machine needs to connect to a VPN using `openconnect` however when I do that I get disconnected from `ssh` since the intranet's IP is no longer valid.

I can reconnect to it from within the VPN using the IP it got assigned but that IP changes everytime the VPN is connected, I don't have control over any other networks only this machine.

Is there a way to keep the `ssh` connection alive while connecting to the VPN?